# get 'this' in nuxt plugin?

Tags: vue.js, plugins, nuxt.js

So you can create a plugin in nuxt like this:

```
const utils = {
  name: utils,
  emmitModel(name, val) {
    const value = Object.assign({}, this.value)
    value[name] = val
    this.$emit('input', value)
  },
}

export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  inject('utils', utils)
}
```

However, in the above, 'this' is not defined.  How do I access the 'this' component context inside emmitModel?

Comment: $nuxt.$emit, instead of this.$emit

Comment: @paddyfields - will that also work for `this.value`?  `value` is a data property on the component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `this` references your Vue instance, wrap your `utils` object in a Vue instance, like so:

```
const utils = new Vue({
  // ..stuff here
})

export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  inject('utils', utils)
}
```

And then within the Vue object you can fully use component methods, computed, data, and access the VM and utils will be injected in nuxt as `this.$utils`